# Getting parsing error when using Gulp-uglify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am minifying my js using Gulp build but getting parsing error. Below is my gulp task:

```
//usemin
gulp.task('usemin', function() {
  gulp.src('./app/main.dev.jsp')
    .pipe(usemin({
      // css: [minifyCss()],
      // html: [minifyHtml({
      //   empty: true
      // })],
      vendorjs: [uglify({
        mangle: true
      })],
      appjs: [
        replace('debug: true', 'debug: false'),
        ngAnnotate({
          remove: true,
          add: true,
          single_quotes: true
        }),
        uglify({
          mangle: true
        })
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
            console.log(e);
            return this.end();
         }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

I tried to console log the error and this is what I am getting:

```
message: 'C:\\PBCOM\\copy_ya\\static-content-youraccount\\scbd\\gulp\\myaccount\\assets\\css\\bootstrap.min.css: Unexpected token: punc ({)',
  fileName: 'C:\\PBCOM\\copy_ya\\static-content-youraccount\\scbd\\gulp\\myaccount\\assets\\css\\bootstrap.min.css',
  lineNumber: 7,
  stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error
```

My gulp-uglify version : "gulp-uglify": "1.4.1",

Comment: Try `gulp-terser`  instead of `gulp-uglify`.  `gulp-uglify` cannot handle es6 features.  I don't know that that is your problem, but you should start there.

Comment: I undersand your point of es6 features. But I am getting error in css file . How is that possible?

Comment: I removed the css file. Now I am getting error in my html tags